# Node.JS with socket.io error on android and mac when using https certificate

Tags: android, macos, node.js, ssl, socket.io

I have a NodeJS server running in parallel with a PHP server to get real-time notifications for the user. The Node server runs expressJS and socket.io.

To create my server using the certificate I do:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var config = require('./config');
var http = require('https');
var fs = require('fs');
var options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync(config.key),
    cert: fs.readFileSync(config.certificate),
    requestCert: true
};
var server = http.createServer(options, app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
server.listen(config.port);
```

The users connect to the server using:

```
connectHTTPS: function() {
        ChatBox.socket = io.connect(ChatBox.serverAddress, {
            port: ChatBox.serverPort,
            secure: true,
        });
    },
```

Code is pretty simple and works fine except for Mac users and Android users. The problem for Mac users is that they will be prompted with a window asking them to select a certificate to authenticate himself. The certificate is something like "com.apple.idms.appleid.prd.(some random string)". 
For Android users, they are prompted with a warning asking them to use a security on their device (pin, pattern, etc.).

The connection still works on Mac users while it is not working on Android. I believe this has to do with the certificates being issued for a certain domain while the connection made to the NodeJS server is the same domain but with a different port.